# Resolving of internal boundaries when using DistMesh generator

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

Mesh generator `ToElementMesh` allows to resolve internal boundaries of the domain to be tesselated:

```
<< NDSolve`FEM`
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{0, 0.5}, {0., 0.}, {1., 0.}, {1., 1}, {0, 
      1.}, {0., 0.5}, {1, 0.5}},
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 4}, {4, 
        5}, {5, 6}, {6, 7}}]}
   ];
mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh];
bmesh["Wireframe"]
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]
[image]

I tried to do the same by means of `DistMesh` generator from [FEMAddOns](https://github.com/WolframResearch/FEMAddOns) package:

```
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]
DistMesh[bmesh]
```

[image]

Is it possible to resolve internal boundaries when using `DistMesh` generator? Thanks in advance for any effort to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `DistMesh` can not resolve internal boundaries. The implementation of `DistMesh` follows the original paper pretty closely.

That being said, the FEMAddOns have a mesh smoothing function called `ElementMeshSmoothing`. `DistMesh` is popular for two reasons. It is a very simple mesh generator and it produces extremely smooth meshes. Now, `ElementMeshSmoothing` does not reach to 'smoothness' level `DistMesh` does, mainly because the `DistMesh` algorithm is very slow. Never the less it may come in handy in some cases. Assuming you are after smooth meshes, then here is an example:

```
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[
   ImplicitRegion[Abs[ 0.7 - Sqrt[ x^2 + y^2 ] ] - 0.3 <= 0, {x, y}], 
   "RegionHoles" -> None];
mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

```
Histogram[mesh["Quality"]]
```

[image]

```
smoothedMesh = ElementMeshSmoothing[mesh]

Show[mesh[
  "Wireframe"["MeshElementStyle" -> Directive[EdgeForm[LightGray]]]], 
 smoothedMesh["Wireframe"]]
```

[image]

Note, that the internal boundary has been preserved.

```
Histogram[{Join @@ mesh["Quality"], Join @@ smoothedMesh["Quality"]}]
```

[image]

Again, `ElementMeshSmoothing` is not a silver bullet, but it can help in some cases. Try it out.